# How do I select only the associated objects in a Rails "where" query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Category, which has_many Products, and a Product in turn has_many Categories. When a user searches for a Category, I'd like to return the products of the matching Categories without losing my Arel object. Here's what I have so far:

```
Category.where("upper(title) like ?", search_term.upcase).map {|category| category.products}.flatten
```

This does the trick of returning the products, but of course what I have is an array and not Arel. I can get as far as adding an `:includes(:products)` clause, so I do indeed get the products back but I still have them attached to their categories. How do I adjust my query so that all I get back is an Arel that only addresses products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is products that you want then you should probably start with the Product object when you are searching. For example ,you could do it like this:

```
Product.joins(:categories).where("upper(categories.title) like ?", search_term.upcase)
```

The reason I use `joins` instead of `includes` is that joins will perform an INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN which is what you need to only return the products that are actually associated with the found categories.

To make it a little more elegant you could wrap it all up in a scope in your Product model like this:

```
# In Product.rb
scope :in_categories_like, Proc.new{ |search_term|
  joins(:categories).where("upper(categories.title) like ?", search_term.upcase) 
}

# In use
@products = Product.in_categories_like(params[:search_term])
```

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) but that's mostly nit picking.

Comment: Just for the record: `def self.in_categories_like(search_term); joins(:categories).where("upper(categories.title) like ?", search_term.upcase); end`.

Comment: If I have `products = Product.in_categories_like('blah')` and I use `categories = products.first.categories`, is it going to query again `Category.where('id in ?', [<categories_id_array>])` or does it know it already by using `join`? I'm not clear about that and I'd like to optimize my query...

Comment: Yes, it will query to retrieve the Categories again. But depending on what result you want, that might not be a bad thing. If you want to list all categories that the Product has, then it is still the correct way. However, if you only want to list the categories that actually matched the search, even though the Product has more categories, you would probably be better of getting the categories first and then retrieving the product from those categories.